# how to obtain fivestar field value in rules?

Tags: 7, rules, rating

I'm trying to a grab a value of a fivestar field within rules and having no luck.

Basically I'm getting users to fill a feedback form and if the fivestar field value is less than 3 Stars then I want the rule to fire but no luck.

Can someone help me figure out to what's going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about forms, since you didn't mention how you set those up on your website, but I can help you with the case where the Rule is called after saving a new comment with a Fivestar field, say it's called *Stars*. Follow the guidelines underneath for your Rule:

**Events:** After saving a new comment.

**Conditions:**

- Check whether the comment has a field *Stars* with *Entity has field*.
- Check whether the field *Stars* is not empty with *NOT Data value is empty*.
- Run this custom code: `return $comment->field_stars['und'][0]['rating']<=60;`.

Adapt these steps to your needs. Be sure to compare the rating with a score out of 100, since Fivestar works internally with percentages.